# Wordpress change post thumbnail attributes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change the post thumbnail's attributes to support [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). This requires me to add a class of `lazy`, change the source to a placeholder image, and place the image source to into a `data-original` attribute.

I've done research and have referenced the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), but am still running into issues.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
<?php
    $tempimg = get_bloginfo('template_url') . "/img/grey.gif";
    $default_attr = array(
        'src' => $tempimg,
        'data-original' => $src,
        'class' => "lazy attachment-$size",
    );
    the_post_thumbnail('project-thumbnail', $default_attr);
?>
```

You'd think it would work, but once I use those attributes, the `$src` and `$size` variables don't work. They're just blank. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I am missing?

Yes. You haven't set either `$src` or `$size` in that block of code. They are blank because the variables are not set. They are, in fact, blank-- arguably less than blank. If you were to set those two values-- something like this--

```
$size = 123;
$tempimg = $src = get_bloginfo('template_url') . "/img/grey.gif";
$default_attr = array(
    'src' => $tempimg,
    'data-original' => $src,
    'class' => "lazy attachment-$size",
);
the_post_thumbnail('project-thumbnail', $default_attr);
```

... it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change all the attributes.

if you just want to give it class lazy.

Just make class attribute to lazy like:

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200), array('class' => 'lazy'));
```

Hope this will help others